# Is the span of $e^{-nx}$ dense in $C([0,1])$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove or disprove: finite linear combinations of the form $\{e^{-nx}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are dense in $C([0,1])$. So by finite linear combinations, does it mean say for some vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$, say $\overline{a}=(a_1,a_2,...,a_d)$, then is $\sum_{k=0}^d a_ke^{-kx}$ dense in $C([0,1])$? And by dense does it mean the closure is the entire space?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, the question is asking whether the set $\mathcal{F} = \{ \sum_{n=1}^N a_ne^{-nx} \, : \,  N \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is dense in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: do I need to show the closure of the set of finite linear combos is all of $C([0,1])$?

Comment: Yes, that is what dense means.

Comment: Are you sure $n$ isn't supposed to start at $0$?  I.e., are constants functions in your set $\{e^{-nx}\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$?

Comment: @JosephCamacho yes! correction has been made!!

Comment: My problem is, I don't know how to write out the closure of the set of all finite linear combinations, let alone explicitly write the span as all continuous functions defined over $[0,1]$.

Comment: I presume you are familiar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem ?

Comment: I was not, thanks!! I am trying to learn a lot of this on my own so I may not have the proper background.

Comment: @StinkingBishop so I can apply the Stone-Weierstrass theorem to it then? Since the set separates points.

Comment: I am really thinking of the original Weierstrass theorem, which claims that the set of all polynomial functions on $[0,1]$ is dense in $C([0,1])$. Of course, your functions are not polynomials. Or, are they?

Comment: @StinkingBishop but are mine polynomial functions? Or I thought I was dealing with linear combos of the exponential function $e$?

Comment: Well, give it a thought!

Comment: So, do I use the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem approximation? I know I can let $F_N(x):=\sum_{k=1}^N a_k e^{-kx}$, then there exists a polynomial for every $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\vert F_N(x) - p(x) \vert < \epsilon.$ for every $x \in [0,1]$. This is by the theorem. Then these polynomials $p$ form the set of limit points of the $F_N$? am I close?

Comment: @JosephCamacho Doesn't matter whether $0$ is included or not: Approximate $e^t$ by the span of $e^{-nt}$ for $n\ge0$, multiply by $e^{-t}$ and you've approximated $1$ by the span of $e^{-nt}$ for $n>0$.

Comment: I have written the answer below, but *there simply must be a duplicate of this somewhere on MSE*. This is a standard exercise in functional analysis, in fact I encountered it as an exercise some $30$ years ago myself!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Proof**: Take any function $f\in C([0,1])$.

Create a new function $g(t)=f(-\ln(t))$ for $t\in[e^{-1}, 1]$. This means that $f(x)=g(e^{-x})$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

That new function $g$ can now be uniformly approximated by polynomials, as per [Weierstrass' Approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Weierstrass_approximation_theorem). i.e. for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a polynomial $p(t)=a_0+a_1t+\ldots+a_nt^n$ such that $|g(t)-p(t)|<\epsilon$ for all $t\in[e^{-1}, 1]$

Now, going back to $t=e^{-x}, x\in[0,1]$: we have $|g(e^{-x})-p(e^{-x})|<\epsilon$ too, for all $x\in[0,1]$. However, notice that $g(e^{-x})=f(x)$ and $p(e^{-x})=a_0+a_1e^{-x}+a_2e^{-2x}+\ldots+a_ne^{-nx}$. Thus, we have found a finite linear combination of $1, e^{-x}, e^{-2x},\ldots$ such that $|f(x)-(a_0+a_1e^{-x}+a_2e^{-2x}+\ldots+a_ne^{-nx})|<\epsilon$.

As this can be done for every $\epsilon>0$, this means that the set of finite linear combinations of $1, e^{-x}, e^{-2x},\ldots$  is dense in $C([0,1])$. $\quad\blacksquare$

---

**Note**: You can also drop $1$ (and even drop finitely many other functions of the form $e^{-nx}$) from the set, and the statement will still be valid.

**Proof**: This is because the interval $[e^{-1}, 1]$ does not contain zero, and it is easy to prove an extension of Weierstrass' theorem that, on an interval $[a,b]$ *not containing zero*, any continuous function can be uniformly approximated by a finite linear combination of $x^d, x^{d+1}, x^{d+2},\ldots$, where $d\ge 1$ is an integer.

Namely, for $\epsilon>0$, take a function $f\in C([a,b])$,  make a *continuous* function $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x^d}$, take $M=\max_{t\in[a,b]}\frac{1}{|x|^d}$, approximate $g(x)$ on $[a,b]$ by a polynomial $p=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n$ to precision $\frac{\epsilon}{M}$, i.e. $\left|\frac{f(x)}{x^d}-(a_0+a_1x+\ldots a_nx^n)\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{M}$, and multiply this inequality by $|x|^d$ to get $|f(x)-(a_0x^d+a_1x^{d+1}+\ldots+a_nx^{d+n})|<\epsilon$. $\quad\blacksquare$